# TYPO3 Scheduler - Webuser not allowed to execute script

Tags: apache, cron, typo3, command-line-interface, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 ver. `9.5.19` and currently trying to execute a cron job with the TYPO3 Scheduler after installing the Aimeos Shop Extension.

I'm getting this error for the Setup Check:

**CLI script
The script to execute the Scheduler from the command line is: "/var/www/vhosts/.../typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run".
The webserver user is not allowed to execute this script.**

How do I allow the Webserver User to execute the script?
I tried to run "/var/www/vhosts/.../typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run" on my Linux server but nothing happened.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate the SuperUser exchange. https://superuser.com/

Comment: In some environments, the webserver has only read/write permission on the binary but is not allowed to execute it. 
So, allow the execution: `chmod u+x  /var/www/vhosts/.../typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3`

Comment: @JulianHofmann thanks that solved my problem! :)

Comment: @JulianHofmann, pls write an answer so it can be accepted. It's useful tip and should be available for others.

Answer (score 1):

In some environments, the webserver user has only read/write permission on the binary but is not allowed to execute it. Check it:

```
ls -al typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
```

Your system should return something like:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 www-data  www-data  895  9 Jun 10:49 typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
```

If there's no `x` at the fourth position, the owner of the binary is not allowed to execute it. At position 7 it would be granted via the group, at last position for everyone/others.

You can grant the permission via

```
chmod u+x typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
```

Answer (score 0):

When the system says `Task failed to execute successfully.`, Starting Scheduler with the task ID helps me.

- For example (when task uid is `8`):

```sh
/usr/local/bin/php typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run  --task=8
```

See the source here: [docs.typo3.org/scheduler](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-scheduler/master/en-us/Installation/SchedulerShellScript/Index.html)

If you have several tasks in Scheduler, then some of them may work, and some may not, when using: `scheduler: run`.
It is necessary for each task to have its own line in the system file and script: `scheduler: run --task=8`. Then all these tasks will work out.